# What will be the formula to check which currency a cell contains?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to check if a cell in google sheet contains $ (USD dollar) currency or Rs. (Pakistani Rupees) currency to calculate two different currencies total?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ It looks as though you're trying to get someone to write code for you which is not what this website is for _ Please add any code attempt that you've tried. You should also visit SO Help Center 'Asking' section to find out more about submitting a properly formatted question _ Doing this will help to ensure that your posts don't receive negative points >>> stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula in `G2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(not(ISBLANK(F2:F)), sumif(LEFT(TO_TEXT(B2:B),1),F2:F,B2:B),))
```

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the sample file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YZmXT9zCXogDLKE400IwqvdeBfdMCJKuouXY8hATp-w/edit?usp=sharing